# wordpress custom comment form

Tags: php, html, forms, wordpress, field

i have a problem, i want to insert in comment form, for everyone fields a div.
i write this code:

```
<?php comment_form(
$fields =  array(
'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' . '<label for="author">' . __( 'Name' ) . '</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span                   class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
            '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '"                      size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p><div id="end-contenuto-post"></div>',
'email'  => '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . __( 'Email' ) . '</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span                         class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
            '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '"                 size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',
'url'    => '<p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">' . __( 'Website' ) . '</label>' .
            '<input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '"                        size="30" /></p>',
'title_reply'=>'Lascia un commento',
'comment_notes_before' => '<p class="comment-notes">I campi contrassegnati da  <span class="required">*</span> sono obbligatori</p>',
)); ?>
```

the error is in 'author' field:

```
<div id="end-contenuto-post"></div>
```

this html not output... why?

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare these variables,

```
$commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();
$req = get_option( 'require_name_email' );
$aria_req = ( $req ? " aria-required='true'" : '' );
```

Answer (score 0):

When it tells you to pass an array as your parameter, you don't do **$fields = array(..)**, instead just use **array(..)** or define your array outside of the comment_form() function and then pass it as a parameter.

Please look at the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form) or [this tutorial](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/wordpress/comment-form-customization/).

Comment: i have delete $field... but not output my html.... argghhhh i read the documentation but not display it.....